# Android Wear APK taking up to days to install

Tags: android, wear-os

I have been trying to install an app to other's devices both by downloading the APK and Google Play alpha testing. It installs on the handheld just fine, but for some reason it takes anywhere from 2 hours to 2 days to install onto the wearable.

The size of my wear APK is less than 2 MB, and the mobile's Gradle matches the wear Gradle as it should.

These devices are pretty old, I believe they are on Android 4.4. Does this have an effect? Android Wear still works for them. We have tried many combinations of restarting the watch, reinstalling the app, and doing a factory reset.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The watch was queuing the apk because the Google Play version was too high (I was using 9.0.0), I lowered it to 7.5.0 (in the Wear gradle) and now it's installing quickly.